# Separating a custom taxonomy from blog post-type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, admin-menu, register-taxonomy

Whenever I invoke `register_taxonomy` in my site's custom plugin, all taxonomies are created as children of the blog post-type in WordPress by default. I just want them to be top-level items in WordPress, not children of the default `blog` post-type. I reviewed the [`register_taxonomy` array parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/) extensively and don't see a way to do this.

Using Admin Menu Editor, it's pretty simple to move custom taxonomies into their own admin menu. But at the system level, is their some hook to make a custom taxonomy its own entity inside of WordPress?

Using breadcrumbs as a mental model, this is the way things currently are:

- Home > Blog > Custom Tax

I just want:

- Home > Custom Tax

Comment: I've written a very extensive [article about modifying the menu](http://unserkaiser.com/blog/2011/12/01/wordpress-admin-menu-in-detail/). In case you find your answer there, please add an answer below.

Comment: I think there is some confusion between admin and permalinks. To remove the `blog` prefix from permalinks use the `with_front` argument ([example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/109540/73)).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. As far as the admin menu is concerned the taxonomies are always "below" the content they apply to. You will always need to directly manipulate the menu structure to change this.

Comment: How would you recommend addressing the incorrect permalink and subsequent breadcrumb trail?

Comment: Oddly the permalink does not include the parent post-type but the breadcrumb trail does...weirdly inconsistent implementation.

Comment: Mark, this is not really an answer. A real answer would show how to achieve (a) removing a submenu item and (b) adding a top menu item.

Comment: @kaiser, sorry but I am not in the habit of providing code for something that I think is a bad design when there is no evidence that there is an actual reasonable need for it. Taxonomies are meta of content there is no logical reason to divorce them from the content at the UX level.

Comment: Please do not assume that you have covered every possibly available and valid use case. A standalone taxonomy is a very valid use case in lots of situations. Example: imagine handling global states for various states in your application. Why would you add the UI to every bit of the application over and over again? Again, please provide a full answer or convert it to a comment. Thanks.

Comment: @staypuftman, what permalink, what, breadcrumbs? You don't have such things in the admin

Comment: @kaiser "no" is a valid answer.

Comment: @MarkKaplun _"Using breadcrumbs **as a mental model**"_

Comment: @toscho But not useful in this case.

Comment: @kaiser, is it you that asking the question, or the OP? As for "no" not being a useful answer, I read some "no" answers on SO that helped stop searching how do to something I can't. I would not call them "not useful" answers.

Comment: I built some custom breadcrumbs that always seem to pull a path that includes my blog category - I think I've got a solution already and actually Mark did answer the question I feel. But @kaiser is right in that there are valid use cases for a physically separate taxonomy. In my case, they are global tagging elements that span 5 custom post-types.

Comment: @staypuftman, it is not that uncommon. but I would say that in that case it might be better to have all the relevant post types at the same menu level

Comment: @MarkKaplun - well agreed. The menus are pretty well laid out already, along the lines you are discussing. I used Admin Menu Editor to give a nice admin-side grouping of post-types and taxonomies. I can fake the breadcrumbs from here. It's just weird that WP offers this strange `null` option for `$object_type` parameter that would logically move the custom tax up to parity with post-type entities but doesn't.